# Using pivot wider to add columns with unique values by group

Tags: r, dplyr

This should be a simple task. The aim is to take each `Team` value in my `df` and create two new `cols` based on the `id` column.

My data:

```
id <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2")
Team <- c("Team_A", "Team_A", "Team_B", "Team_B", "Team_C", "Team_C", "Team_D", "Team_D")

df <- data.frame(id, Team)
```

Output:

```
  id   Team
1  1 Team_A
2  1 Team_A
3  1 Team_B
4  1 Team_B
5  2 Team_C
6  2 Team_C
7  2 Team_D
8  2 Team_D
```

What is should look like:

```
Team_1 <- c("Team_A", "Team_A", "Team_A", "Team_A", "Team_C", "Team_C", "Team_C", "Team_C")
Team_2 <- c("Team_B", "Team_B", "Team_B", "Team_B", "Team_D", "Team_D", "Team_D", "Team_D")

df <- data.frame(id, Team, Team_1, Team_2)
```

Output:

```
  id   Team Team_1 Team_2
1  1 Team_A Team_A Team_B
2  1 Team_A Team_A Team_B
3  1 Team_B Team_A Team_B
4  1 Team_B Team_A Team_B
5  2 Team_C Team_C Team_D
6  2 Team_C Team_C Team_D
7  2 Team_D Team_C Team_D
8  2 Team_D Team_C Team_D
```

So, e.g. for `id` 1, there were only two teams `Team_A` and `Team_B` and so on.

I tried `pivot_wider` and `spread` but I still could not manage this. I often got the error `Values from` Team `are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 df %>%
    mutate(Team_ = list(unique(Team)), .by=id) %>%
    unnest_wider(Team_, names_sep ='')

# A tibble: 8 × 4
  id    Team   Team_1 Team_2
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 1     Team_A Team_A Team_B
2 1     Team_A Team_A Team_B
3 1     Team_B Team_A Team_B
4 1     Team_B Team_A Team_B
5 2     Team_C Team_C Team_D
6 2     Team_C Team_C Team_D
7 2     Team_D Team_C Team_D
8 2     Team_D Team_C Team_D
```

Comment: thank you! I couldn't quite figure that one out.

Comment: `unnest_wider` is definitely underestimated!